# Making invisible characters visible in NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a NSTextField and I want to give the user the opportunity to make invisible characters like blanks, carriage returns and tabs visible. Unfortunately I didn't find a word in Apple's documentaion about this. I assume I'm not using the right term when looking for it.

Any clues how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd go for a NStextView instead, where the associated NSLayoutManager and NSTextStorage components are already set for you. Then, you can achieve what you are trying to do by doing the following steps:

- Subclass NSATSTypesetter to draw custom glyphs for any characters you
  want by overriding :

  ```
  - (void)drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphsToShow atPoint:(NSPoint)origin
  ```

  - (NSRect)boundingBoxForControlGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex forTextContainer:(NSTextContainer *)textContainer    proposedLineFragment:(NSRect)proposedRect    glyphPosition:(NSPoint)glyphPosition    characterIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex
- Subclass NSLayoutManager and set its type setter with the above one.
  Then override:

-(void)drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphsToShow atPoint:(NSPoint)origin
{
        [self.typesetter drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:glyphsToShow atPoint:origin];

[super drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:glyphsToShow atPoint:origin];

}

- Replace the layout manager of the NSTextView with the above one:

  [[textView textContainer] replaceLayoutManager:[[[MyLayoutManager alloc] init] autorelease]];

Basically, you have to check NSLayoutManager and NSATSTypesetter classes for anything related to text custom drawing. Also there is a detailed guide about all this [here](https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/TextLayout.html).

Comment: This sounds very interesting Samir, thanks a lot. I'll give it a try next weekend.

Comment: In the above example, why is it necessary to subclass NSATSTypesetter? (By just subclassing NSLayoutManger, you can already override drawGlyphsForGlyphRange, call its super and then do anything you want); Why is it necessary to call drawGlyphsForGlyphRange on your own typesetter?